# Need help registering dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I am having trouble registering a dependency with Microsoft's inbuilt Dependency Injection library. I have no idea where to go from here and I feel all over the place. Upon starting the web application I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' while attempting to activate
>   'Services.Repositories.Repository`1[Domain.Person]'.

Below is my Context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connString) : base(connString) { }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
    }
```

Next is my Repository class:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

My services class:

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _repo;

    public PersonService(IRepository<Person> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IQueryable<Person> AsQueryable()
    {
        // TODO: Fix Queryable functionality
        return _repo.GetAll();
    }

    public Person CreatePerson(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dob)
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName = lastName,
            DOB = dob
        };
        return person;
    }

    public void DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        var person = _repo.GetById(id);
        _repo.Delete(person);
    }

    public Person UpdatePerson(int id, string firstname, string lastName, DateTime dob)
    {
        var person = _repo.GetById(id);
        person.FirstName = firstname;
        person.LastName = lastName;
        person.DOB = dob;
        return person;
    }
}
```

My Controller class:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonService _personService;
    public HomeController(IPersonService personService)
    {
        _personService = personService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And this is where I have registered everything so far:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddScoped<MyContext>(_ => new MyContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString")));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IPersonService), typeof(PersonService));
    }
```

What do I seem to be missing? This has been giving me a headache for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only adding `MyContext`, but do not associate it with `DbContext`. Try something like

```
services.AddScoped<DbContext>( _ => new MyContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("connString")));
```

or change your repository to expect `MyContext` in the constructor instead of `DbContext`

Comment: Fantastic eye! Such a simple fix. Thank you so much Mats391, your answer has fixed my issue.